# OpenAL WaveData Error

Tags: java, audio, wav, openal, lwjgl

I have a problem with playing a sound using OpenAL in Java (LWJGL).
Whats worse is I have no idea what the error is telling me.

*AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed*

Now I'm sure that the file location is correct but waveFile is returning a null, So the error is on line 8; when it's trying to get data from the waveFile.

```
FileInputStream fin = null;
try {
    fin = new FileInputStream("res/FancyPants.wav");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
WaveData waveFile = WaveData.create(fin);
AL10.alBufferData(buffer.get(0), waveFile.format, waveFile.data, waveFile.samplerate);
waveFile.dispose();
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try wrapping the FileInputStream in a BufferedInputStream. Like this.

```
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    BufferedInputStream bin = null;
    try
    {
        fin = new FileInputStream("res/FancyPants.wav");
        bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WaveData waveFile = WaveData.create(bin);
    AL10.alBufferData(buffer.get(0), waveFile.format, waveFile.data, waveFile.samplerate);

    waveFile.dispose();
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks very much. I can now do it in one single line too `WaveData data = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("res/FancyPants.wav")));`